# Machine Learning: Should I choose classification or recommendation?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, classification

I don't know how I should approach this problem:

I have a data set. A user may or may not be part of a funded scheme.
I want to use machine learning to deduce that users that are not part of the scheme were susceptible to certain conditions e.g. 1,2,3 and 4. Those in the scheme were susceptible to 1,2 and 4. Therefore it can be deduced that if you are part of the scheme you won't be susceptible to condition 3.

I have a second related problem as well. Within the funded scheme the user can have two plans (cost different amounts). I would like to see whether those on the cheaper plan were susceptible to more conditions than those on the more expensive plan.

Can anyone help me as to whether this a recommendation or a classification problem and what specific algorithms I should look at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. It's a statistics problem. Your dataset is complete and you don't mention any need to predict attributes of future subjects or schemes, so training a classifier or a recommender wouldn't seem to serve it's usual goals.

You could use a person's conditions as features and their scheme stats as the target, classify them with SVM and then use the classification performance/accuracy as a measure of the separability of the classes. You could also consider clustering. However, a t-test would do the same thing and is a much more accepted tool to justify the validity of claims like this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build a system that would classify a user as funded or not funded, and if not funded, reason why they were not funded.

If this is the case, what you need is a machine learning classifier that is interpretable, i.e., the reasoning behind why a classifier makes a certain decision can be conveyed to users. You may want to look at Decisions trees and (to a lesser extent) RandomForest and Gradient Boosted Trees.